# Annoying compound path Appearance vfx inheritance behavior

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

When using the pathfinder to exclude overlapping shapes from another shape, the base shape will inherit the visual fx applied to the overlapping shapes. How can I prevent the "bottom" (base) shape from having the same vfx?

Steps to reproduce:

> 1. Draw a large random shape with corners using the pen tool
> 2. Draw a small rectangle contained within the blob
> 3. Add Appearance > Stylize > Rounded Corners to the rectangle
> 4. Use Pathfinder > Exclude with both shapes selected
> 5. Note that the blob/splat inherits the rounded corners vfx

How can I keep the rounded corners on the rectangle, but lose them on my "random shape"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the rounded rectangle with the effect and choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu.

If the rounded rectangle has a stroke, you need to also choose `Object > Expand` after expanding the appearance.

Then proceed with your Pathfinder operations.

Note: This "bakes in" the rounded corner effect so it's no longer "live" and adjustable. However, there's really no other way if you use effects.